# Investing in a fund

Tags: investing

I am looking to invest some personal money of around £5000.

I understand to give your money to a hedge fund you need to have a high net worth.

Lets say I want to invest in the Goldman Sachs India Equity Portfolio which has generated great returns in the past.

Is there anyway for me to invest £5000 into this fund?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do *not* need to have 'high net value', and yes, you can invest in it.

Typically, fund companies require a *minimum investment*, that could be 100, it could be a 1000. 5000 should be enough for 99.9 % of all funds for an initial investment.

What you *need* is an investment company that manages the account for you. I cannot name those for your country, but they should be easy to find (companies like IMG, and Fidelity might serve your country). You then open an account with the company of your choice, transfer the money, and tell them which fund it shall go in; all this is possible *online*.

You can also go to see an agent in person, and he will fill the forms for you, and handle all the action, but he might take a fee for it.

Comment: I thought to invest in a hedge fund you needed to have around a million dollars minimum?

Comment: This is great. So all these amazing returns which some funds get, it is possible for me to get those returns?

Comment: Yes. Just understand that they might as well _lose_ money, and you would be a part of it too. They don't promote their losses, obviously, but they happen too.

Comment: Ok, so the whole process works like buying normal ftse 100 stock i.e I can check all prices on Bloomberg etc,,? And I can buy and sell at any time?

Comment: Generally, yes. Some funds have minimumwait times, some might have up to 30 days, especially foreign and specialty fonds, but most don't; and typically buy and sell only happens _once per day_. You need to check for each fund.

Comment: How much do fidelity charge when you ask them to buy and sell?

Answer (score 5):

According to my research one only needs £5000 to invest in this fund.  However, it also has a sales charge of 4% with an annual charge of 1.75%.  If this is short term money, you would have to have a fairly high return to break even.

Comment: According to [this sheet](http://www.goldmansachs.com/gsam/docs/funds_international/fund_updates/monthly_fund_updates/mfu_indiaeq_en.pdf) it's even worse: 5.5% sales charge and a 2.25% per annum charge. Lots of fees!